# Magento 2 quality patches MDVA-28656 is not available in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, sales-order, patches, virtual-products

I'm using Magento 2.4.1, when I order a virtual product then create a pending invoice it will make the order status become closed instead of processing. To prevent this error I must apply Magento quality patches MDVA-28656. The problem is MDVA-28656 patch available at Magento quality-patches v1.0.4, while Magento 2.4.1 requires this Magento quality-patches with minimum version 1.0.8.

[image]

this documentation states the MDVA-28656 available at v1.0.4 https://devdocs.magento.com/quality-patches/release-notes.html

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on 2.3.6-p1.

I applied patch manually from (be careful,link for os magento version):
[magento quality path repository](https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/blob/1.0.4/patches/os/MDVA-28656__fixes_order_status_issue_when_invoicing_zero_payment_orders__2.3.5-p1.patch)